# shared values between classes in Java

Tags: java

I have a problem and I need your help. We have two different classes.

class 1 :

```java
public class class1 {
    
    private String value = randomValue();
    
    public String randomValue() {
        int x = (1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((100000 - 1) + 1))) + (1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((90 - 1) + 1)));
        return String.valueOf(x);
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

---

class 2 :

```java
public class class2 {

    class1 c = new class1();

    public String valueClass2() {
        return c.getValue();
    }
}
```

The problem is that I want to get the value of X in the first class, so that I can use it in the second class.

Is there a clear way to do this? Thank you

Comment: Make it an instance variable and provide a getter.

Comment: If class2 has a dependency on class1 then consider [injecting](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/a-quick-intro-to-dependency-injection-what-it-is-and-when-to-use-it-7578c84fa88f/) that dependency into class2.

Comment: how can I do that ? When I am in the second class and I am doing my object from the first class .. Once I do that, there will be a difference in the values

Answer (score 0):

Differentiate between classes and the instances of a class. If you create a new instance of `class1` in an instance of `class2`, you cannot access the data of another, previously created instance of `class1`.
Declare a `class2` `constructor` that takes an instance of `class1`. You can then access a previously created instance of `class1` and call `getValue()` as in your example.

An example:

```
public class class2 {
    private class1 c;

    // Constructor that accepts a reference to your instance of class1
    public class2(class1 class1Instance) {
        // TODO: prevent that (class1Instance == NULL)
        
        this.c = class1Instance;
    }

    public string valueClass2() {
        return c.getValue();
    }
}
```

To better distinguish between a class and an instance of a class, it is recommended that class names always begin with an uppercase letter. The variable name of the instance always starts with a lower case letter.

e.g.

```
Class1 class1Instance = new Class1();
// do something with class1Instance ...
Class2 class2Instance = new Class2(class1Instance);
```

I hope that I recognized your problem correctly and that my hints are a solution for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help ... I will try it ... although my problem is a little more complicated than what I explained .. my problem is in Java Frame++

Answer (score -1):

```java
public class class1 {

    private int x;
    
    private String value = randomValue();
    
    public String randomValue() {
        x = (1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((100000 - 1) + 1))) + (1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((90 - 1) + 1)));
        return String.valueOf(x);
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
}
```